# How to create a 3 parameter function that gets its maximum in the center of the cube?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I have an problem where I have a 3 dimensional board, and I want to assign to the center of that cube (aka the board) maximum values and to the edges of the board lower values (preferably in a way so that the upper left side will get higher values then the lower right side) - so i have a cube with R rows, C columns and depth D. I have a coordinate inside the cube with coordinates (i,j,d), With the following constraint on the values  (0,0,0)<=(i,j,d)<(R,C,D). I want a function that will map each value (i,j,d) to distinct values between 0 inclusive to R*C*D non inclusive in a way that the medium of the cube will get the highest values, then the upper left side and then the lower right side.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume each cell is identified by (i,j,d) and the maximum values are (I,J,D). Assume that i,j, and d start at 1, and that I, J, and D are odd so that there is a unique middle value on each axis, $M_I = (I+1)/2, M_J = (J+1)/2$, and $M_D = (D+1)/2$

Then the distance from the center, for example in i, is 
$$|i-M_I|$$
We can make the maximum value 1 in the center and apply a penalty for moving away. The simplest way to do this would be:

$$V = 1 - \frac{|i-M_I|}{3(I-M_I)} - \frac{|j-M_J|}{3(J-M_J)} -\frac{|d-M_D|}{3(D-M_D)} $$

But this is symmetric, with all the corners giving 0. If we want to introduce asymmetry, so that the upper left will be higher than the lower right, we can define
$$f(i-M_I) = i-M_I, for \ \ i\geq M_I$$
$$f(i-M_I) = \frac{2}{3}\left(M_I - i\right), for\ \ i<M_I$$
This function f is similar to the absolute value, but increases more slowly for negative values than positive ones, so we will get an asymmetric penalty like this:

$$V = 1 - \frac{f(i-M_I)}{3(I-M_I)} - \frac{f(j-M_J)}{3(J-M_J)} -\frac{f(d-M_D)}{3(D-M_D)} $$

Answer (score 0):

Pick a function in each direction and multiply them.  Ignoring the right being higher than the left and letting the board range from $0$ to $1$, a nice one is $4(x-\frac 12)^2$.  It has a peak of $1$ at the center and is zero at the ends.  For 3D, just use $64(x-\frac 12)^2(y-\frac 12)^2(z-\frac 12)^2$

Comment: peak of 1 at the center and zero at the ends... maybe i'm missing something, but isn't it $4x(1-x)$?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1-4(x-1%2F2)%5E2)

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont:  you are right.  The square works, too, if we make the factor $16$ and it will be more peaked in the middle.

Comment: so $(4x(1-x))^{p_x}(4y(1-y))^{p_y}(4z(1-z))^{p_z}$ has independent peaknesses $p_x, p_y, p_z$ and still max $1$...
For asymmetry, $x^m(1-x)^n$ is nice, but it does not have the peak at $x=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont Hi thanks for the help. But your suggested function has only one variable. My problem is a 3-dimentional cube so I have 3 variables at least - can you explain how you meant I can use your function?

Comment: my first comment only has $x$, but the second comment has three variables $x,y,z$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the suggestion - I still don't understand something - the cube size is dynamic in every "Round" - so I need to create a  function that given cube size - numOfRow, numOfCols, cubeDepth, will output a value between 0 to 1 for all coordinates (i,j,d) which are by the way not between 0 to 1, but between 0 and the corresponding dimension they represent. So I am not sure how your suggested function takes all this variables into account. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @JaumeOliverLafont Thanks I see now. My latest comment to  RossMillikan also applies to you - can you please explain how I can use your function?

Comment: You just let my $x$ be the fraction of the distance across the cube.  So if the cube runs from $5$ to $12$ inclusive, you would map $5$ to $0$, $12$ to $1$, and the points in between linearly.

Comment: @RossMillikan Hi, believe I wasn't clear enough. I posted a clarification on what function I am looking for. I will appreciate if you can take a look and help me with that.